# Can't view deleted questions via Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

When using the Android app, I am unable to view deleted questions on any site. I simply get, "Loading the question failed." However, I can view these sites normally in the browser using the same account, so I don't see why I would be restricted access to them via the dedicated app.

Questions attempted:

- [recursion - Adding numbers [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012373/recursion-adding-numbers) (20k+ on this site)
- [Who is the smartest anime character? [on hold]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/who-is-the-smartest-anime-character) (9k+ on this site, but it's a beta site)

Both questions fully load in the browser on my computer or my Android device, but when opening them via the app, as mentioned, I receive the error that, "Loading the question failed." If I'm already looking at a question pre-deletion, and it is deleted, refreshing it gives an, "Unable to refresh" error.

I don't know if we're just not intended to look at deleted questions on the Android app (yet?), but I figured this would just be a provided feature, so that makes me think this is probably a bug.

Comment: Does the API expose deleted posts (I don't think it does)? If not, this is not possible.

Comment: @animuson Seems you may be right, the documentation says nothing about it. Would this be a feature request for the API, then?